# NodeJs port only works via local network

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I set up a simple NodeJs server:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world'); // try res.json() if getList() returns an object or array
});
app.listen(3000);
```

Now when i visit http://server.domain.com:3000/ on the local network, i receive the correct response, but on 3G mobile device i recieve a no response timeout.

Server is equipped csf v6.28 Firewall

I will need the script to be accessible by all users..

Comment: We can't really answer this as we have no idea what your network architecture is.

Comment: @Quentin Can you give me some ideas of where the issue may be?

Comment: No. It is a waste of time to speculate about what your network architecture might be.

Comment: @Quentin It seems i can't access domain.com with mobile device either. Looks like i have been blacklisted by csf or something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems CSF had perm blocked me, as i forgot to list 3000 as an allowed port.